# Computing $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^{n^2} e^{-x^2}n\sin\frac{x}{n}\,dx$?

Tags: integration, limits, lebesgue-integral

I am trying to compute this integral/limit, I don't feel like I have any good insight...

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^{n^2} e^{-x^2}n\sin\frac{x}{n} \, dx.$$

I have tried to make a change of variable to get rid of the $n^2$, I changed to $X=\frac{x}{n^2}$ but got something even worse, I've tried to reach a situation where I could use a convergence theorem for Lebesgue Integrals,... I'm not sure I'm even on the right track!

Could you give me a hint on how to start this?

Thank you very much!

Comment: I might be missing something here, but the upper limit doesn't really make a difference here, it's going to be $+\infty$ no matter what letter you use.

Comment: Just a comment that could help you reach the answer, $n\sin(1/n) \to 1$, since this is the derivative of $\sin(x)$ evaluated at $0$. Thus $n\sin(x/n) \to x$ by the chain rule. A good guess as to the result of the integral is that it should agree with $\int_0^\infty xe^{-x^2} dx$. You can find this integral using $u$ substitution.

Comment: Also for any fixed interval, $n\sin(x/n) \to x$ uniformly. For large $x$ values $e^{-x^2}$ will make the integral small. Thus you can split the integral in to a finite part and an infinite part. The finite part you can pass the limit through the integral (dominated convergence if you wish), and for the infinite part work out a bound in terms of $e^{-x^2}$. Just an idea.

Comment: @Joel Computing engines agree with you ! Both integrals give $\frac{1}{2}$... I'm trying to come up with a proof using your ideas!

Comment: Right...I suggest changing it to $\int_0^\infty$, and showing that the added part (from $n^2$ to $\infty$) is bounded by, say, $1/n$, so it has no effect. You can then perhaps write out a series for $n \sin (x/n) = x - \frac{x^3}{n^23!} + \ldots$, use that to split the integral into two parts, compute the first one directly (just integrate $x \exp(-x^2)$) and show that the remaining one is bounded by $C/n$ for some constant $C$.

Comment: When you have got $\int_{0}^{\infty}$, you split it into two parts? You mean that the first part will come from the first term of the series and the second from the rest?

Comment: Yes, exactly right. At least, that's what I would do. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Observe that
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^{n^2} e^{-x^2} n \sin \left( \frac{x}{n}\right) dx = \lim_{n\to \infty} \int_0^\infty f_n(x)dx $$
where
$$f_n(x) = e^{-x^2} n \sin \left( \frac{x}{n}\right) \textbf{1}_{[0,n^2]}(x)$$
where $\textbf{1}$ denotes the indicator function.

Now observe that
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} n \sin \left( \frac{x}{n}\right) = x$$
uniformly and
$$|n \sin \left( \frac{x}{n}\right)| \leq |x|$$
for all $n\geq 1$. As a result,
$$|f_n(x)| \leq |x| e^{-x^2}$$
which is clearly integrable on $(0,\infty)$. Hence we can push the limit inside the integral by Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem: Thus
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^{n^2} e^{-x^2} n \sin \left( \frac{x}{n}\right) dx = \int_0^\infty \lim_{n\to \infty} f_n(x)dx  = \int_0^\infty x e^{-x^2} dx =\frac{1}{2}.$$

Comment: Right, that indicator function solves the whole problem of making this rigorous! I only have one doubt: how exactly do you get $|n\sin(\frac{x}{n})|≤|x|$? You mean that holds on $[0,n^2]$ for all $n$?

Comment: Well you can define $g(x):=n \sin(x/n) - |x|$ and show that $g\leq 0$ for any $n\geq 1$ for instance. That holds for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$ (because we have absolute value of $x$)

Answer (score 1):

Notice that 
$$\int_0^{n^2} n\sin(x/n)e^{-x^2} dx=\int_0^{n^2} \left(n\sin(x/n)-x\right)e^{-x^2} dx + \frac{1-e^{-n^4}}{2}.$$
Moreover $|\sin(t)-t|\leq t^2$ implies $\left|n\sin(x/n)-x\right|\le n(x/n)^2=x^2/n$. Therefore
$$\left|\int_0^{n^2} \left(n\sin(x/n)-x\right)e^{-x^2} dx\right|\leq 
\int_0^{n^2} \left|\left(n\sin(x/n)-x\right)\right|e^{-x^2} dx\leq
\frac{1}{n}\int_0^{\infty} x^2e^{-x^2} dx$$
and the right-side goes to zero as $n\to+\infty$.
It follows that
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_0^{n^2} n\sin(x/n)e^{-x^2} dx=\frac{1}{2}.$$